# CSS/HTML Header Background Color Not Covering Entire Width of Page

Tags: html, css, background, header, background-color

[Image with visual aid for what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKPcs.png)

Hello,

I am working on designing a web page, and I am trying to get my background color to cover the entire header area. However, it keeps having an area around it that is the main page's background. I have tried adding borders and messing with the padding, but all that does is decrease the of the information inside of the header.

Is there a way to get the background color for the header to reach the top of the page and all the way out to both sides of the page?

```css
/* our body class */

body {
  background-color: #0077BE;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1C39BB;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome to Samuel Ohrenberg's portfolio!</h1>
    <center>
      <ul class='navList'>
        <li class='navButton' a href='index.html'>Home</text>
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">&#8659; Portfolio Items &#8659;</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="programPage.html">Programs</a>
                <a href="otherProjects.html">Other Projects</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <li class='navButton' a href='videoInterview.html'>Video Interviews</text>
      </ul>
    </center>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are challenging the default margin of body. Just remove the default margin from body:

```css
body
{
    background-color: #0077BE;
    margin:0;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1C39BB;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to Samuel Ohrenberg's portfolio!</h1>
        <center>
            <ul class='navList'>
                <li class='navButton' a href='index.html'>Home</text>
                <li> 
                    <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&#8659; Portfolio Items &#8659;</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="programPage.html">Programs</a>
                            <a href="otherProjects.html">Other Projects</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <li class='navButton' a href='videoInterview.html'>Video Interviews</text>
            </ul>
        </center>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: That's so simple! Thank you!

Just a quick follow-up, is there a just-as-easy way to get the background color to reach the top of the page? So the entire top section is the darker color, and then it goes to the lighter color?

http://i.imgur.com/HlyQSjv.png

Comment: The blank space above the header is of h1. Set the `margin-top:0` for `h1`

Comment: You can search for `reset.css` to reset all default properties to null. However you may have to redefine default behavior for some elements.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, you need to set margin of your elements.
By default I do this (reset margin and padding for all elements):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

In your sample, it will look like this:
    http://codepen.io/alebon/pen/gwaoNO